# How do I store correlation values between users in a database using MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a database of users for a website that will store correlation values between all the users. What I mean by this is that for every pair of users, there is a stored value of correlation between the two users.

The correlation values will be calculated by PHP using a correlation algorithm. My question is what is the most correct way to store them in a MySQL database? I realize I could make a table like this:

```
         ---------------------------------
        | user1 | user2 | user3 | etc... |
 -----------------------------------------
| user1 | #val  | #val  | #val  | #val   |
 -----------------------------------------
| user2 | #val  | #val  | #val  | #val   |
 -----------------------------------------
| user3 | #val  | #val  | #val  | #val   |
```

etcetera. But I don't like this method because

- It stores every value twice; for example the correlation between user1 and user3 is stored in row 1 column 3 as well as row 3 column 1.
- I use prepared statements, which means I can't select columns named after user IDs unless I concatenate the user ID into the SQL statement, which is obviously not ideal.

What are my alternatives? If this can be done in MySQL well, how do I go about it?

If this can't be done well in MySQL, are there any other database types I should try to learn? For example, I realize a graph database system may work well for this, but I don't want to spend time learning how to use a graph database if this can be done in MySQL.

Comment: read up on database normalization, it will help you understand how to break your entity into tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would do something like this in a JOIN table.  So say you have a `users` table that has a `user_id` field and whatever other fields you need.  You could build a table called `user_relations` or similar that would simply have two user_id foreign key fields that would relate users in some manner.

```
user_id_1  |   user_id_2
------------------------
1          |   2
1          |   3
2          |   1
3          |   1
...        |   ...
```

You would then have a compound primary key across both columns to enforce uniqueness. Note that I am assuming that the `#val` you mentioned in your question was simply some kind of flag (1/0) that represents the existence of a relationship.  If you actually need that value to explain something about the relationship (i.e. parent/child or some other meaningful value) then you can obvioously add a third column to this table to store the value associated with the relationship.

When you need to query across a relation you could do it like this:

```
SELECT u1.*, u2.*
FROM
  users AS u1
  INNER JOIN user_relations AS ur
    ON u1.user_id = ur.user_id_1
  INNER JOIN users AS u2
    ON ur.user_id_2 = u2.user_id
WHERE u1.user_id = ? /* or whatever filter you may need to apply */
```

Note that depending on what type of relationship you are trying to represent (i.e. a two-way relationship) you may need two rows in the table to represents each relationship.  That way you can always use the first column to look up all related users in the second column.  This is shown in my example above where the relationships of user one are shown in both directions in the sample rows values.

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly - each row in the table represents a relationship of two users? Is this a particularly "correct" way of doing this?

Comment: @VijayRamamurthy Yes you are understanding correctly.  This is absolutely a preferred way of normalizing such relational data.  You could require two rows of data for each relation rather than one (see added comments in my answer above). Another option, if you have a maximum of one relation per user, would be to simply add a relation column in the user table and do a self-join (you sometimes see this done to express parent relationships in relational representations of tree structures)

Comment: I will be storing decimal values, each anywhere between 0 and 1, in this. So I would be using your second approach. My main question is about efficiency. Would this method be inefficient in terms of data storage or computing time, compared to a graph database?

Comment: @VijayRamamurthy It is always hard to give definitive answers on performance. As there are a number of variables that come into play, including hardware, data access patterns, etc.  If you have proper indexes on your fields to match you queries, enough memory allocated to store the indexes fully in memory, and you are not dealing with hundreds of millions of rows on these tables, you probably should be OK.

Comment: One thing I've noticed about this is that each correlation is stored twice; eg 1 to 3 is in the 2nd as well as the 4th. Is there a way to get around this? I know I could just store each once, but then how would I query this?

Comment: @VijayRamamurthy If you are only ever going to be looking up relationships in one direction, or if for example 1->2 has a different decimal value than 2->1, then there is no need for duplication, because you have in essence a one-way relationship.  If the relationship is two-way, then I would suggest duplicate records.  This is really no more difficult to mange than single records, as you can insert both rows of the relationship in a single INSERT query.

Comment: The only thing I worry about with this is the number of rows. If I have 10 users, that is 100 rows. 1000 users becomes a million rows. ten thousand users is a tenth of a billion rows. It seems scary how the number of rows increases exponentially; eg adding each new user to the users table results in adding [however many rows in the users table] rows to the user_relations table. This just seems scary to me as an inexperienced point of view. Is this exponential growth really nothing to worry about?

Answer (score 1):

Brilliant question.

Given users A, B, C, D and E, your data set is triangular;

```
  A B C D E
A   
B *  
C * *
D * * *
E * * * *
```

1. In the above matrix AA, BB, CC, DD and EE are meaningless.
2. To avoid duplication, AB is the same as BA. CD is the same as DC, and so on.

You could save a triangular data-set in a table-orientated SQL database in this way;

```
id usr usr c
------------
0  A   B   1
1  A   C   5
2  A   D   3
3  A   E   4
4  B   C   3
```

etc

Comment: I considered that but that's really messy in MySQL.

Comment: What's messy about it? Do you mean the code to handle it is messy in some way?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean - it would have to involve concatenation into SQL queries I think. Unless you know of an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best solution is to have 2 tables... Users and UsersRelations

UserRelations:

```
====================================
User1Field | User2Field | ValueField
====================================
#User      | #User      | #val
------------------------------------
#User      | #User      | #val
------------------------------------
#User      | #User      | #val
------------------------------------
```

Comment: Your answer is very similar to Mike Brant's answer - I'm just wondering if this method may be considered unelegant. I don't have much experience in MySQL so maybe this is a valid approach; I'm just wondering if it might be better for me to learn a graph database system to avoid inefficiencies.

Comment: This is the correct (or most userd) way to do it on relationship databases... if you can change the DB motor... you should use NoSQL like MongoDB...