# What is the most ideal way (compatible with php) to store correlation values in a database?

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if my title is unclear. I'm making a website with PHP where users can submit posts. I'm currently using a MySQL database to store users and posts. I want to also store the values of correlation between each user and each post. This is the idea:

```
        -----------------
        | user1 | user2 |
-------------------------
| post1 | #val  | #val  |
-------------------------
| post2 | #val  | #val  |
-------------------------
```

I wish I could make a table like this in MySQL but I can't select column names with prepared statements unless I concatenate into a query, which is obviously not ideal.

[I've asked a similar question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328321/how-do-i-store-correlation-values-between-users-in-a-database-using-mysql-and-ph) and the response was to make a three-column table, in which each row represents a correlation. Like so:

```
=======================
| user | post | value |
=======================
| usr1 | pst1 | #val  |
-----------------------
| usr2 | pst1 | #val  |
-----------------------
| usr1 | pst2 | #val  |
-----------------------
| usr2 | pst2 | #val  |
-----------------------
```

I don't like this. It stores a lot of extraneous data since it stores each user's id several times and each post's id several times. It also needs a crazy number of rows; if I just had 100 posts and 100 users, that would be 10,000 rows.

I'm not afraid to add another database to my project (or switch to another database type entirely if I like it) to accommodate for this. I know there are many NoSQL databases out there but I have no experience with anything outside of MySQL and I don't know what database suits my needs.

Are my concerns of doing this in MySQL reasonable? Or can MySQL handle that many rows? Is there another method of doing this in MySQL that is more efficient? If not, I would like to know what the best database type for this is.

This seems like a very common type of thing to store, but I don't see a reasonable way to do it in MySQL; therefore I would imagine there is a database type out there perfectly suited to doing this.

Comment: What I think you're missing is that MySQL is only a constant factor worse than the most optimal way of storing it. Sure, for 100 users and 100 posts, you have 10,000 rows, but with an 'optimal' solution, you have 10,000 cells. MySQL does not scale very well here, but neither does any other solution.

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't like that MySQL idea because for each of the 10,000 cells I would only be storing the correlation value, but in the MySQL solution I would have to store the user id and post id in each row. This basically triples the data stored. Plus. I've heard MySQL doesn't do well with too many rows (I'll have more than 50 users and 50 posts on this site)

Comment: I don't believe "MySQL doesn't do well with too many rows". That's what databases are *for*: storing rows. If MySQL can't perform the main function of a database very well, then what kind of database is it? MySQL is a somewhat reputable database, so I'd assume it does, in fact, handle large numbers of rows very well.

Comment: Okay, but I still wonder if there is another option that doesn't involve storing triple the data I need to store.

Comment: What is this correlation algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basics of relational storage is the same undependently of which databae you use.
You should of course aim to avoid redudant database-designs. That is the whole point of relational databases...

But now to the actual issue! :-)

I think you're just looking for an alternative from the answer you recieved before.

```
=======================
| user | post | value |
=======================
| usr1 | pst1 | #val  |
-----------------------
| usr2 | pst1 | #val  |
-----------------------
| usr1 | pst2 | #val  |
-----------------------
| usr2 | pst2 | #val  |
-----------------------
```

I would create three tables. One main-table and two link-tables.

main-table: **main:**

```
=============================
| user_id | post_id | value |
=============================
| 1       | 1       | #val  |
-----------------------------
| 2       | 1       | #val  |
-----------------------------
| 1       | 2       | #val  |
-----------------------------
| 2       | 3       | #val  |
-----------------------------
```

link-table 1: ***user***

```
===============
| id | name   | 
===============
| 1  | Mark   |
---------------
| 2  | Sohpie |
---------------
```

link-table 2: ***post***

```
===========================
| id | post               | 
===========================
| 1  | How are you?       |
---------------------------
| 2  | The nuts are brown |
---------------------------
| 3  | Milk is white      |
---------------------------
```

***Then you can just do join like this to get the data:***

```
SELECT u.name, p.post, m.val FROM main m
LEFT JOIN ON user u ON (m.user_id = u.user_id)
LEFT JOIN ON post p ON (m.post_id = p.post_id)
```

**Result should be something like:**

```
Mark, How are you, #val
Sophie, How are you, #val
Mark, The nuts are brown, #val
Sophie, Milk is white, #val
```

I'm not sure of how you mean by the #val (how is it calulated?), but I hope this answer will give you a clue how you could solve the rest.

Comment: I have an algorithm to calculate #val that is beyond the scope of this question. As for the idea of having 3 tables - yes I was going to do that anyway; I assumed that was implied (sorry for the lack of clarity). The reason I was reluctant to do this was that there would be a lot of rows and a lot of extraneous data being stored (see my comments on my question)

Comment: yes, thank you. I think I'll end up doing this and not worrying about my fears of having too many rows.